# switchbuf in vim results in an empty buffer

Tags: vim, buffer, macvim

I have the following setting in my `~/.vimrc`

```
set hidden
set switchbuf+=usetab,newtab
```

The second line allows me to open files from QuickFix window in a new tab when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Everything works fine, but when a new file is opened in a new tab, it results in an new empty buffer in the buffer list.

Is it possible to have the above feature without this new empty buffer?

I am using the following version of macvim

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 25 2013 10:33:00)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-52
Compiled by Homebrew
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing an implementation detail. In `buflist_getfile()` (found in `src/buffer.c`), the `switchbuf=newtab` is handled by this code:

```
if (swb_flags & SWB_NEWTAB)     /* Open in a new tab */
    tabpage_new();
```

Basically, Vim performs a `:tabnew` followed by the `:edit file` command, whereas a `:tabedit file` would be better, because it avoids the empty tab page (which has to display something, so an empty buffer is created).

Admittedly, this is mostly a cosmetic issue, but I can understand that it bothers you. You can raise this on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php); ideally with a patch that fixes the problem.